# Combination of Join with Not Join in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

My question relates to R data.table with multiple keys. take this example:

```
library(data.table)
example(data.table)
key(DT)
[1] "x" "y"
```

and suppose I want a variation of "x not equal b and y not equal 3", as in here:

```
DT[!J("b",3)]
   x y  v v2  m
1: a 1 42 NA 42
2: a 3 42 NA 42
3: a 6 42 NA 42
4: b 1  4 84  5
5: b 6  6 84  5
6: c 1  7 NA  8
7: c 3  8 NA  8
8: c 6  9 NA  8
```

The variation I want is "x EQUAL b and y NOT equal 3", as in here:

```
DT[J("b",!3)]
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, J("b", !3)) : 
  typeof x.y (double) != typeof i.V2 (logical)
```

Any chance of telling J() to negate some keys?
Thanks!

Comment: I find the follow syntax a bit more transparent: `DT[ x == 'b' & y != 3]`

Comment: Hi @GaryWeissman, your syntax implies a vector scan. The point of data.table and join operations is to avoid exactly those, by using keys. But I guess you are right that for non data.table users that is easier to understand.

Comment: I don't think the `J` function supports non-concordant logical operators between arguments.  I believe the above syntax is still faster in DT than in DF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For composite keys** you can use the following

```
 DT[.("b")][!.(x, 3)]   # x is the name of first column of key
```

In general, you can chain together several `[ ] [ ]` to filter down to the results you need.

---

Note that you can also easily use logical statements in the `i` of `data.table`.
 The `J()` -- or now `.( )` -- syntax, is simply a shorthand convenience.

You can use almost anything that would go inside an `if` clause, with the advantage of accessing the column names as variables.

In your specific example,  you would use `x=="b" & y != 3`
*note the single `&`, not `&&`.*

```
 DT[  x=="b" & y != 3]
```

You can also combine vector scans with the binary search of data.table as follows

```
 DT[.("b")][y != 3]
```